# Name which introduced by friend declaration

Tags: c++, friend

I'm considering N3797 working draft. There is a quote from 3.3.1/4

> friend declarations (11.3) may introduce a (possibly not visible) name
>   into an enclosing namespace

And further in 3.3.2/11 I found

> Friend declaration refer to function or classes that are member of the
>   nearest enclosing namespace, but they don't introduce new name into
>   that namespace.

So the name declared by friend declaration is not visible or doesn't introduce at all?

Comment: It can be found by Argument Dependent Lookup, but only that way.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So does that name still introduce? It become invisible in an enclosing scope. Am I right?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is unclear what in the standard does mean. If it doesn't introduce at all it is curiously to found this name in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be found by Argument Dependent Lookup, but only that way.

E.g. you can implement a comparison operator that way:

```
struct Point
{
    int x, y;

    friend
    auto operator<( Point const a, Point const b )
        -> bool
    {
        // compare and return true or false
    }
};
```

The name (here `operator<`) is not visible in the enclosing scope, but is found when the function is invoked with arguments of type `Point`.

---

The current rules are designed to be backward-compatible with the so called **[Barton-Nackman trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick)**.

Quoting the Wikpedia article on that:

> “When investigating the possibility of removing friend name injection from the C++ programming language, Barton and Nackman’s idiom was found to be the only reasonable use of that language rule. Eventually, the rules for argument-dependent lookup were adjusted to replace friend name injection by a less drastic mechanism, described above, that maintained the validity of Barton and Nackman’s technique”

where **“friend name injection”** refers to earlier rules where the name did become visible in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I'm interesting in questions asked in the comments to.

Comment: Is there exist examples of such "not visible" names besides the class type names which can be accessed via elaborated-type-specifier?

Comment: @St.Antario: a `friend` name such as `operator<` above can't be accessed via elaborated-type-specifier. It's not a member of the class. It's a member of the enclosing namespace, but is just not visible there (which e.g. prevents name collisions from multiple uses of the Barton-Nackman trick and similar coding techniques). I'm not really sure how to take the address. Maybe someone who's done that recently will chime in.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you have in mind, but it should always be possible to just add a declaration for it, and you can limit the scope of that declaration to where you need it. (`struct S { friend void f(S) { } } int main() { void f(S); void (*fp)(S) = f; fp(S()); }`) Note: this fails with GCC and Sun C++, but works with clang and Intel. I see no reason why this wouldn't be valid, but if it is indeed invalid, moving the declaration to file scope is enough to fix that.

Comment: But why section 3.3.2/11 said that the `Friend declaration refer to function or classes that are member of the nearest enclosing namespace, but they don't introduce new name into that namespace.`?

Comment: @hvd I don't understand the contradicts between 3.3.1/14 and 3.3.2/11. First tells that the name declared by friend specifier i introduce int the nearest enclosing namespace but second tell that it is not.

Comment: @St.Antario My comment was only a response to Alf's "I'm not really sure how to take the address."; I don't know why the standard is worded the way it is, and TBH, I'm confused by it too.